# Install Anaconda along with Spyder and Tensorflow on Windows 7 PC that doesn't have internet connectivity

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, spyder, windows-7-x64

I'm in need of installing Anaconda along with Spyder and Tensorflow on a Windows 7 laptop that does not have a connection to the internet. Is this possible and if so, would there be directions on how to do this?

Thanks...

Comment: I'm sure you can, but why? Just connect to a network.

Comment: Not allowed to, due to work requirements.

Comment: Easiest way to do this is to grab a computer with internet access and plug it in to the windows 7 laptop using an ethernet cable to share the internet access to that computer. That way, only the approved machine is connected to the work wifi, and everything routes through that mini-lan to the win7 machine.

Comment: New software can only be added through the use of CDs/DVDs/thumbdrives etc, then the media stays in the lab.

Comment: Sounds like you just answered your own question. "New software can only be added through the use of CDs/DVDs/thumbdrives etc, then the media stays in the lab"

Comment: Sounds like you need to get another computer, take it out of the lab, install anaconda to a flashdrive, then install the packages you need to that flashdrive, then plug it in to the lab computer and point the path to the installation on the flashdrive.

Comment: Side note... this is the weirdest set of requirements ever. If it's for security, well, you have no security because you're allowing flash drives to enter, which are more dangerous than an internet connection. If you allow flash drives it's not an air-gapped system.

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/:

> **Installing Anaconda on a non-networked machine (air gap)**
>
> Obtain a local copy of the appropriate Anaconda installer for the
>   non-networked machine. You can copy the Anaconda installer to the
>   target machine using many different methods including a portable hard
>   drive, USB drive or CD. After copying the installer to the
>   non-networked machine, follow the detailed installation instructions
>   for your operating system.

This will include Spyder, but not Tensorflow. There are [a number of questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tensorflow+install+without+internet) on here about how to install Tensorflow offline.

I think the laborious part will be ensuring you have the right versions of all dependencies, so you might want to start by creating an Anaconda env on a networked machine that has the packages and dependencies you need, then copy the downloaded conda packages from that machine to a folder on the non-networked machine. Then you can specify that folder as a channel, using a `file://` URI, in a `conda create` or `conda install` command.

An alternative could be to use Docker, if you can use a pre-built container or build one yourself?